# How to merge two MySQL results?

Tags: php, mysql, merge

I execute 2 queries on 2 different servers with the same table structure.
How can I merge the 2 arrays in PHP?

Answer (score 4):

[PDO::query()](http://php.net/pdo.query) returns a [PDOStatement](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object which implements the interface [Traversable](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php).
The [SPL](http://uk.php.net/spl) class [IteratorIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoriterator.php) wraps any Traversable to act like an [Iterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php).
And another SPL class, [AppendIterator](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.appenditerator.php), can "concatenate" Iterators to act like one single iterator.

```
<?php
$result1 = $pdo1->query('SELECT * FROM foo');
$result2 = $pdo2->query('SELECT * FROM foo');

$it = new AppendIterator;
$it->append(new IteratorIterator($result1));
$it->append(new IteratorIterator($result2));

foreach($it as $row) {
  echo join(', ', $row), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to make this Appended iterator Seekable? (i.e. Make it possible to jump to specific places within this AppendIterator to get a subset of the data?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at  [array_merge](https://www.php.net/array_merge).

`array array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] )`

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values
> of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the
> resulting array.
>
> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
> for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
> contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
> value, but will be appended.
>
> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with
> incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind, when You query two database servers, You will have a collision between the id's of the records (db auto_increment feature) unless You're using UUID for each record identification.

So when You're not using uuid for the generation of ids of the records, when You merge the two arrays with results, you should mark wchich one is from with server to avoid collisions later.